# Cannot resolve annotation parameter

Tags: java, annotations

I study annotations and in one of learning tasks I must inject some implementations of cache annotated as `@Cache` to fields annotated as `@InjectCache`.

I wrote this code but I get `cannot resolve symbol name()` error on expression `cache.getAnnotation(Cache.class).name()` but `field.getAnnotation(InjectCache.class).name()` couple of strings earlier resolves without errors.

`@Cache` and `@InjectCache` both has parameter `name()`, and they only difference is a `@TARGET` annotation.

```
  package annotations;

  import annotations_test.MapCache;
  import annotations_test.SortedMapCache;
  import java.lang.reflect.Field;
  import java.lang.reflect.Type;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  public class Injector {
        public static void inject(Object instance){
            List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
            List<Class> caches;
            caches = addAllCaches();
            fields = getAnnotatedFields(fields, instance.getClass());
            try {
            for (Field field : fields) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                String name = field.getAnnotation(InjectCache.class).name();
                Boolean implementation_not_found = true;
                for (Class cache: caches){

                        if (name.equals(cache.getAnnotation(Cache.class).name())){
                            implementation_not_found = false;
                            field.set(instance, cache.newInstance());

                        }
                }
                if (implementation_not_found){
                    throw new TypeNotPresentException(Cache.class.getTypeName(),null);
                }

            }
            }catch (TypeNotPresentException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

This is what `@Cache` looks like:

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;



@Target(value= ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Cache {
    String name();
}
```

And `@InjectCache`:

```
package annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;



@Target(value= ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(value= RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface InjectCache {
    String name();
}
```

Comment: Could you please add import declarations to your code snipped or links in the text so that we know exactly about what annotations you are talking.

Comment: Try to clean the project and recompile everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `Class cache` in the for loop is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

You need to change it to have a generic type (even if it is just the wildcard `<?>`):

```
for (Class<?> cache: caches) {
  // ...
}
```

The reason for this is, that you can't use any generic methods with raw types. Without the wildcard, the return type of `getAnnotation(Cache.class)` is `Annotation` and not the `Cache` annotation type.

Adding the wildcard is your best option because it makes the `getAnnotation` method type-safe. You can also cast it to the right type though:

```
((Cache)cache.getAnnotation(Cache.class)).name()
```

Comment: Thank you!
Changing to generic type helped me,